# How to delete duplicated values in python?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, record-linkage

[I have added an excel image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVLXt.png)! I deduplicated an excel sheet using python. After deduplication, it has a `cluster id` column. A set of duplicate rows can have cluster id as 0, denoting that those n rows have are same. Now, for a unique row, there is no value for cluster id, not even none, it's just empty.
I want to delete only those rows that have a `cluster id` value so that I can have all the distinct rows. For deduplication, I am using `pandas_dedupe` library.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_dedupe as pdd
df=pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df=pdd.dedupe_dataframe(df,['firstname','lastname','gender','zipcode','address'])
#deletion part to be written here
df.to_csv('sample_deduplicated.csv')
```

Comment: Rewrite your post including snippet code

Comment: Can you post an example of your code?

Comment: you need `drop_duplicates(subset=['cluster_id'])` check the docs

Comment: @Datanovice, This deletes all the data. I want to keep all the rows that have unique cluster id values and also all those that have no cluster Id values.

Comment: @DejeneT, added that!

Answer (score 0):

By what I understand, you wish to keep all rows with empty `cluster id` column and drop rows which have value in `cluster id` column.

You could simply put filter conditions to take only empty `cluster id` rows.

```
df[df['cluster id'].isna()]
```

For reference on *Series.isna()* please refer the [documentaion](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html).

Comment: This keeps only the rows with first name: Babita and Vikas whereas I want to keep all the unique values and delete only the duplicates. Refer to the screenshot that I have posted. Thanks for the help though!